# How do you optimize M and L values of a B Tree

Tags: tree, complexity-theory, b-tree

If you knew how many elements were going to be stored in a B-tree, how would you determine the optimal values of M and L? Can performance be determined in terms of M and L?

Answer (score 0):

You can't optimise the 'M and L values' of a B-tree because they are concepts from the realm of academia, where 'performance' is synonymous with asymptotics.

The terms 'optimisation' and 'performance' are from the real world, where B-tree nodes tend to have fixed physical sizes - based on things like storage sector/cluster sizes, memory page sizes, cache sizes (and cache line sizes, for intra-page organisation) - and node capacities in terms of keys or pointers are 'whatever fits in the physical page'. Keys tend to be variable in size and key compression can fit wildly different numbers of keys into nodes, depending on the degree to which the keys share common prefixes or suffixes - or the degree to which they are compressible, for schemes that use bona fide compression.

This also means that 'page underful' criterion does not correspond to a fixed number of keys/pointers relative to the maximum capacity, and in some cases even completely empty pages are kept around for a while. This means that the whole math thing gets altogether fuzzy.

Some niche applications have fixed key sizes, so that academic math does carry over to some extent. Other niche applications put the actual key data wherever it might fall in the free store and put only pointers into the actual B-tree nodes. This hugely compromises performance but the results can still be better than the alternatives.

If you tell us what your actual problem/project is and what kind of performance you're aiming for then we can give you specific advice. For that it would also be important to know things like the expected relative frequencies of updates vs. searches/queries.